# SFDX 2GP: cannot create new managed package version

Tags: salesforcedx, managed-package, salesforcedx-cli, 2gp, 2gp-ama

I need to add a new class to an existing 2GP managed package. I get the following error when I attempt to create the package using the SF CLI.  How do I resolve this issue when I attempt to build it?

> We couldn’t create this package version because new components were
>   added or existing components were deleted. Remove components
>   {ApexClass=[ckz_PIM_ScheduledCacheRebuild]} from the package version,
>   and create the package version again.

UPDATE

The current managed package that was released was 1.0.2

I modified my sfdx-project.json so that the ancestorId is set to the 1.0.2 package id.

The versionNumber is set to 1.0.3.0

I still get the same error message when attempting to create the managed package.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you set a new target number for the version with appropriate ancestor version?

Comment: @PhilW the previous version was 1.0.2.0, so I was trying to create 1.0.3.0.  Is that the right way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

I worked with a colleague on this.  The answer was to create the new package version as 1.1.0-1.  For some reason, using 1.0.3.0 was not accepted.  Having the beta version number be something other than zero was the answer.

Comment: I am seeing similar error.

Add components {Profile=[Admin]} back into the package version, and create the package version again.

This is my current sfdx-project json of managed package :

"versionName": "1.2",
"versionNumber": "1.2.0.NEXT",
"ancestorVersion": "1.1.0.1"
And now I am creating new beta package with this:

"versionName": "1.3",
"versionNumber": "1.3.0.NEXT",
"ancestorVersion": "1.2.0.1"
any suggestions?